# How to highlight a region in a Pgfplots graph based on an axis' values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to highlight the region where the two measures below, represented with dots and error bars, agree:

[image: Error bars with region of agreement.]

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=30,xmax=70,ymin=0,ymax=3,unit vector ratio=1 2,ytick=\empty,xtick={30,40,...,70}]
\addplot +[blue,scatter,only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic,
error bars/.cd, 
y dir=both,y explicit,x dir=both,x explicit] 
table[row sep=crcr, x index=0, y index=1, x error index=2, y error index=3, meta index=4 ] 
{45  1   5  0  1\\  
 56  2   8  0  2\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See **4.17.1 Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways of doing that. I'm assuming you want to highlight the whole height of the axis, if you don't need that there's less trickery, just use a sensible y-value.

In general you can `axis cs` (axis coordinate system) to place stuff using the axis coordinates, so for example `\draw (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:1,2);`. However, if you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or newer, the most recent version is 1.12) `axis cs` is the default, so you get the same with `\draw (1,1) -- (1,2);`. This goes of course for paths placed inside the `axis` environment.

Another useful thing is that you can get the values of the axis limits with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}`, and similar for `ymax`, `xmin` and `xmax`. This leads to the first of the three options:

```
\fill [red,opacity=0.3] (48,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle (50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
```

A variant of this is to make use of the fact that the axis box is a node named `current axis`. This can be used along with the perpendicular coordinate system to get the same effect:

```
\fill [pattern=north east lines,opacity=0.2] (48,0 |-current axis.south east) rectangle (50,0 |-current axis.north west);
```

When writing `(50,0 |- current axis.north)` you get the coordinate that has the x-coordinate of (50,0), and the y-coordinate of `current axis.north`. In other words, `|-` means in this case "draw a vertical line from the first coordinate, and a horizontal line from the second, and use the intersection of those".

The third way uses `\addplot`, so for this no `compat` setting is needed:

```
\addplot [pattern=north west lines,densely dotted,opacity=0.6] coordinates {
         (48,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
         (50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
        }
        \closedcycle;
```

I use the same two coordinates as the first `\fill` above, and add `\closedcycle` at the end. `\closedcycle` means that area under the curve is filled.

Other notes:

- The `patterns` library is only loaded to get the two different `pattern` fills, which I used just to be able to illustrate all in one.
- The `backgrounds` library provides the `on background layer` option used for the `scope` environment. This does what you'd think, it placed the paths in the `scope` below the other stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=30,xmax=70,ymin=0,ymax=3,unit vector ratio=1 2,ytick=\empty,xtick={30,40,...,70}]
\addplot +[blue,scatter,only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic,
error bars/.cd, 
y dir=both,y explicit,x dir=both,x explicit] 
table[row sep=crcr, x index=0, y index=1, x error index=2, y error index=3, meta index=4 ] 
{45  1   5  0  1\\  
 56  2   8  0  2\\};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [red,opacity=0.3] (48,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle (50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

\fill [pattern=north east lines,opacity=0.2] (48,0 |-current axis.south) rectangle (50,0 |-current axis.north);

\addplot [pattern=north west lines,densely dotted,opacity=0.6] coordinates {(48,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) (50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})} \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```