# Place arrow and text at specific point in a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

This code is building off the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286178/fill-area-above-and-below-lines-in-pgfplots).  How do I go about adding an arrow and text like this to the second plot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix,backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{filecontents*}{data23.csv}
A   B   C   D
0   -14.9000001 100 -100
0.0000064   8.83999991  100 -100
0.0000128   -3.73000002 100 -100
0.0000192   -2.80000019 100 -100
0.0000256   8.83999991  100 -100
0.000032    15.82999992 100 -100
0.0000384   8.37999988  100 -100
0.0000448   -1.4000001  100 -100
0.0000512   -6.99000001 100 -100
0.0000576   -11.6400001 100 -100
0.000064    -2.33000016 100 -100
0.0000704   0.4599998   100 -100
0.0000768   -1.4000001  100 -100
0.0000832   -19.10000014    100 -100
0.0000896   0   100 -100
0.000096    -4.19000006 100 -100
0.0001024   -15.84000015    100 -100
0.0001088   -5.13000011 100 -100
0.0001152   17.23000002 100 -100
0.0001216   7.44999981  100 -100
0.000128    10.24000001 100 -100
0.0001344   -2.33000016 100 -100
0.0001408   8.37999988  100 -100
0.0001472   -63.80000019    100 -100
0.0001536   -1851.47    100 -100
0.00016 -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001664   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001728   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001792   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001856   -919131.57  100 -100
0.000192    194777.73   100 -100
0.0001984   238253.27   100 -100
0.0002048   277420.5    100 -100
0.0002112   291163.1    100 -100
0.0002176   286195.89   100 -100
0.000224    255122.31   100 -100
0.0002304   182965.3    100 -100
0.0002368   74969.14    100 -100
0.0002432   1717.82 100 -100
0.0002496   -46980.57   100 -100
0.000256    -60135.04   100 -100
0.0002624   -87181.11   100 -100
0.0002688   -82944.99   100 -100
0.0002752   -64264.06   100 -100
0.0002816   -42486.94   100 -100
0.000288    -19782.69   100 -100
0.0002944   -1171.61    100 -100
0.0003008   13164.71    100 -100
0.0003072   21098.18    100 -100
0.0003136   23432.54    100 -100
0.00032 22276.77    100 -100
0.0003264   18429.47    100 -100
0.0003328   11196.82    100 -100
0.0003392   4662.66 100 -100
0.0003456   -366.48 100 -100
0.000352    -3680.12    100 -100
0.0003584   -6535.09    100 -100
0.0003648   -7723.93    100 -100
0.0003712   -7477.13    100 -100
0.0003776   -6128.57    100 -100
0.000384    -3032.39    100 -100
0.0003904   -317.5800002    100 -100
0.0003968   248.1899998 100 -100
0.0004032   1216.77 100 -100
0.0004096   2771.61 100 -100
0.000416    3422.14 100 -100
0.0004224   1918.52 100 -100
0.0004288   947.6199999 100 -100
0.0004352   -420.96 100 -100
0.0004416   -2162.53    100 -100
0.000448    -1460.78    100 -100
0.0004544   153.6599999 100 -100
0.0004608   302.6799998 100 -100
0.0004672   605.8199999 100 -100
0.0004736   -415.8400002    100 -100
0.00048 -997.9200001    100 -100
0.0004864   -1122.25    100 -100
0.0004928   -926.2000001    100 -100
0.0004992   -723.6400001    100 -100
0.0005056   284.98  100 -100
0.000512    81.01999998 100 -100
0.0005184   572.29  100 -100
0.0005248   385.0999999 100 -100
0.0005312   -301.75 100 -100
0.0005376   -298.96 100 -100
0.000544    418.1599999 100 -100
0.0005504   71.7099998  100 -100
0.0005568   839.1199999 100 -100
0.0005632   1733.19 100 -100
0.0005696   1055.65 100 -100
0.000576    -544.3600001    100 -100
0.0005824   -648.2000001    100 -100
0.0005888   -1442.62    100 -100
0.0005952   -778.5900002    100 -100
0.0006016   398.1399999 100 -100
0.000608    1222.36 100 -100
0.0006144   1837.5  100 -100
0.0006208   -152.74 100 -100
0.0006272   -1656.83    100 -100
0.0006336   -477.77 100 -100
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
    minor grid style={dashed,red},
    major grid style={dotted,green!50!black},
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={color=blue,scriptsize,it,bf},textfont={color=blue,scriptsize,it,bf},labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setcaptionsubtype
\begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=1 by 2
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
            }
            ,width=10cm
            ,height=6cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={\bfseries{\emph{\footnotesize{Number of Recursions}}}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
\nextgroupplot[xmin = 0, xmax = 0.7]%
\addplot [blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space] {data23.csv};\label{plots:ltone}

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 500, ymin = -500, xmin = 0, xmax = 0.7]%
\addplot [blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space,restrict y to domain=-10000:10000] {data23.csv};\label{plots:lttwo}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick,name path=A] table[x index=0,y index=2, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space]{data23.csv};
\addplot [draw=none,name path=B, domain=0:.6336, mark=none] {500};
%\addplot [red, fill opacity=0.1] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=0:0.6336}];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [red!20] (0,100) rectangle (0.7,500);
\fill [red!20] (0,-100) rectangle (0.7,-500);
\end{scope}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick,name path=C] table[x index=0,y index=3, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space]{data23.csv};
\addplot [draw=none,name path=D, domain=0:.6336, mark=none] {-500};


\end{groupplot}

\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption[]{Test 1\label{subplot:ltone}}};
\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r2.north) {\caption[]{Test 2\label{subplot:lttwo}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]{Plot showing position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$}\label{abserror}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having added `name path=plotA` to the blue plot, you can use

```
\draw [-latex, shorten >=3pt, name intersections={of=plotA and A,name=i}] (0.2,420) node[left]{Text here} to[out=350,in=160] (i-1);
```

Note that it takes a while to compile, perhaps because there are a lot of intersections. The `name intersections` part is from the `intersections` library, which I believe is loaded by `fillbetween`. Also note that the coordinate (0.2,420) is found just by looking at the values on the axes.

You could of course just read off the coordinate of the intersection from the axis, which makes it much quicker to compile, though the coordinate is perhaps less precise. For example

```
\draw [-latex] (0.2,420) node[left]{Text here} to[out=350,in=160] (0.34,110);
```

is not so bad.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix,backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{filecontents*}{data23.csv}
A   B   C   D
0   -14.9000001 100 -100
0.0000064   8.83999991  100 -100
0.0000128   -3.73000002 100 -100
0.0000192   -2.80000019 100 -100
0.0000256   8.83999991  100 -100
0.000032    15.82999992 100 -100
0.0000384   8.37999988  100 -100
0.0000448   -1.4000001  100 -100
0.0000512   -6.99000001 100 -100
0.0000576   -11.6400001 100 -100
0.000064    -2.33000016 100 -100
0.0000704   0.4599998   100 -100
0.0000768   -1.4000001  100 -100
0.0000832   -19.10000014    100 -100
0.0000896   0   100 -100
0.000096    -4.19000006 100 -100
0.0001024   -15.84000015    100 -100
0.0001088   -5.13000011 100 -100
0.0001152   17.23000002 100 -100
0.0001216   7.44999981  100 -100
0.000128    10.24000001 100 -100
0.0001344   -2.33000016 100 -100
0.0001408   8.37999988  100 -100
0.0001472   -63.80000019    100 -100
0.0001536   -1851.47    100 -100
0.00016 -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001664   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001728   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001792   -959001.16  100 -100
0.0001856   -919131.57  100 -100
0.000192    194777.73   100 -100
0.0001984   238253.27   100 -100
0.0002048   277420.5    100 -100
0.0002112   291163.1    100 -100
0.0002176   286195.89   100 -100
0.000224    255122.31   100 -100
0.0002304   182965.3    100 -100
0.0002368   74969.14    100 -100
0.0002432   1717.82 100 -100
0.0002496   -46980.57   100 -100
0.000256    -60135.04   100 -100
0.0002624   -87181.11   100 -100
0.0002688   -82944.99   100 -100
0.0002752   -64264.06   100 -100
0.0002816   -42486.94   100 -100
0.000288    -19782.69   100 -100
0.0002944   -1171.61    100 -100
0.0003008   13164.71    100 -100
0.0003072   21098.18    100 -100
0.0003136   23432.54    100 -100
0.00032 22276.77    100 -100
0.0003264   18429.47    100 -100
0.0003328   11196.82    100 -100
0.0003392   4662.66 100 -100
0.0003456   -366.48 100 -100
0.000352    -3680.12    100 -100
0.0003584   -6535.09    100 -100
0.0003648   -7723.93    100 -100
0.0003712   -7477.13    100 -100
0.0003776   -6128.57    100 -100
0.000384    -3032.39    100 -100
0.0003904   -317.5800002    100 -100
0.0003968   248.1899998 100 -100
0.0004032   1216.77 100 -100
0.0004096   2771.61 100 -100
0.000416    3422.14 100 -100
0.0004224   1918.52 100 -100
0.0004288   947.6199999 100 -100
0.0004352   -420.96 100 -100
0.0004416   -2162.53    100 -100
0.000448    -1460.78    100 -100
0.0004544   153.6599999 100 -100
0.0004608   302.6799998 100 -100
0.0004672   605.8199999 100 -100
0.0004736   -415.8400002    100 -100
0.00048 -997.9200001    100 -100
0.0004864   -1122.25    100 -100
0.0004928   -926.2000001    100 -100
0.0004992   -723.6400001    100 -100
0.0005056   284.98  100 -100
0.000512    81.01999998 100 -100
0.0005184   572.29  100 -100
0.0005248   385.0999999 100 -100
0.0005312   -301.75 100 -100
0.0005376   -298.96 100 -100
0.000544    418.1599999 100 -100
0.0005504   71.7099998  100 -100
0.0005568   839.1199999 100 -100
0.0005632   1733.19 100 -100
0.0005696   1055.65 100 -100
0.000576    -544.3600001    100 -100
0.0005824   -648.2000001    100 -100
0.0005888   -1442.62    100 -100
0.0005952   -778.5900002    100 -100
0.0006016   398.1399999 100 -100
0.000608    1222.36 100 -100
0.0006144   1837.5  100 -100
0.0006208   -152.74 100 -100
0.0006272   -1656.83    100 -100
0.0006336   -477.77 100 -100
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
    minor grid style={dashed,red},
    major grid style={dotted,green!50!black},
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={color=blue,scriptsize,it,bf},textfont={color=blue,scriptsize,it,bf},labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setcaptionsubtype
\begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=1 by 2
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
            }
            ,width=10cm
            ,height=6cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={\bfseries{\emph{\footnotesize{Number of Recursions}}}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
\nextgroupplot[xmin = 0, xmax = 0.7]%
\addplot [blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space] {data23.csv};\label{plots:ltone}

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 500, ymin = -500, xmin = 0, xmax = 0.7]%
\addplot [name path=plotA,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space,restrict y to domain=-10000:10000] {data23.csv};\label{plots:lttwo}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick,name path=A] table[x index=0,y index=2, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space]{data23.csv};
\addplot [draw=none,name path=B, domain=0:.6336, mark=none] {500};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [red!20] (0,100) rectangle (0.7,500);
\fill [red!20] (0,-100) rectangle (0.7,-500);
\end{scope}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick,name path=C] table[x index=0,y index=3, x expr=\thisrow{A}*1000, col sep=space]{data23.csv};
\addplot [draw=none,name path=D, domain=0:.6336, mark=none] {-500};


\draw [-latex] (0.2,420) node[left]{Text here} to[out=350,in=160] (0.34,110);

% the slow version
%\draw [-latex, shorten >=3pt, name intersections={of=plotA and A,name=i}] (0.2,420) node[left]{Text here} to[out=350,in=160] (i-1);
\end{groupplot}

\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption[]{Test 1\label{subplot:ltone}}};
\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r2.north) {\caption[]{Test 2\label{subplot:lttwo}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]{Plot showing position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$}\label{abserror}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```